# Segmentation error when comparing member of an array with integer

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

I've been writing an linked graph realisation program, with the ability to find shortest path.
This is my funcion for printing. I have an array with paths marked I try to sort them here, and print, but in the line **if(pathTaken[i] == src)** I am getting a segmentation error. What might be wrong here?

```
    void printShortestPath(int pathTaken[], int n, int src, int dest)
    {
        int i = n-1;
        int j = 0;
        int toCompare;
        int printingOrder[n];
        int startingnumber;
        int stopper = 1;
        printingOrder[j] = dest;
        while(stopper != 0)
        {
            j++;
            pathTaken[i] = printingOrder[j];
            i = pathTaken[i];
            if(pathTaken[i] == src)
            {
                stopper = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                if(j > n)
                {
                    printf("No path from %d to %d found", src, dest);
                    stopper = 0;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only check `if (j > n)` but actually `j == n` is off bounds, also you can use `else if` instead of a separate `else` and `if`, like this

```
else if (j >= n)
{
    printf("No path from %d to %d found", src, dest);
    stopper = 0;
}
```

or you could add the condition to the `while` control like

```
while ((stopper != 0) && (j < n))
```

or you could use a `for` loop, which seems the natural choice here

```
for (j = 0 ; ((stopper != 0) && (j < n)) ; ++j)
```

Comment: Still getting the same issue. My program doesn't like the. **if(pathTaken[i] == src)** part. It crashed during compilation and debbuger points to this line.

Comment: Then it's your compiler.

Comment: No, it was my stupidity. Rather than setting values in Printing order, i messed up the array of path taken.  **pathTaken[i] = printingOrder[j];** Should have been **printingOrder[j] = pathtTaken[i];** Thanks for the help anyway.